# I need 2 clicks to click a button when I have a jcombobox focused

Tags: java, swing, focus, jbutton, jcombobox

## EDIT 2

[image]

Here is a brief pic of the problem. I could not take the picture while the popup of the jcombobox was on display, but the thing is if i have the popup on display, i cannot click the jbutton, it only unfocuses.

## EDIT 1

My following question is, I have an editable jcombobox, and a button to its right.

The thing is I cannot make use of just a single click and do the actionlistener of the button, first I need to lose the focus of the jcombobox, and then click on the jbutton.

Is there another way so that it is done in one click?

Sorry for not posting any images, I do not have the reputation for it.

Thanks for your attention and patience.

Comment: Sorry for not posting any images, I do not have the reputation for it. ---> post an SSCCE/MCVE short, runnable, compilable, demonstrate a.m. issue descrined in yuor question

Comment: Sorry again, I am new, where do I post that, in the same question? or you prefer an image on some site?

Comment: by default, standard here is in the questions body, EDIT you question, select all inserted code and to use code tag

Comment: can't to demonstrate this issue, event from JButton is fired on 1st mouse_click, is not required two mouse events for ...

Comment: Use comboBox.setFocusable(false); and always try to post an MCVE for quick help.

Answer (score 0):

you can check the click count. 
if `clickcount==1` focus lost the combo box and if `clickcount==2`,do whatever you want.